# How to init Jquery Mobile flexslider before dynamically loaded page show?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, flexslider

I have a multi page jquery mobile app.  The primary page is part of the first html file.  The second page is dynamically loaded.

I have the same flexslider 2 header on top of both pages.

When I navigate to the second page (fade transition) the flexslider header is the last thing to load.  This has an undesired effect of "popping" the html to make room for the flexslider header.

I would like to have the page transitions seamless and smooth.  I would like to have the flexsliders already loaded with a nice fade transition.

I have tried everything that I know of to have the second page's flexslider setup before the transition or new page show to no avail.

If fact, I can only get flexslider to work(loads after pageshow) if I use the below code:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    setup_flexslider();
});
```

I have tried the following events with no luck:

```
 pagecontainerbeforetransition
 pagecontainerbeforeshow
```

Any ideas how to make this work?  Is it even possible on dynamically loaded jquery mobile pages?

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
     <div id="title_flexslider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="/static/graphics/imgs/img_project_title.png" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function setup_flexslider() {

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
        selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
        animation: "slide",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
        easing: "swing",               //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!
        direction: "horizontal",        //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
        reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
        animationLoop: true,             //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
        smoothHeight: false,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode
        startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
        slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
        animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
        initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
        randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order

        // Usability features
        pauseOnAction: true,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when interacting with control elements, highly recommended.
        pauseOnHover: false,            //Boolean: Pause the slideshow when hovering over slider, then resume when no longer hovering
        useCSS: true,                   //{NEW} Boolean: Slider will use CSS3 transitions if available
        touch: true,                    //{NEW} Boolean: Allow touch swipe navigation of the slider on touch-enabled devices
        video: false,                   //{NEW} Boolean: If using video in the slider, will prevent CSS3 3D Transforms to avoid graphical glitches

        // Primary Controls
        controlNav: false,               //Boolean: Create navigation for paging control of each clide? Note: Leave true for manualControls usage
        directionNav: false,             //Boolean: Create navigation for previous/next navigation? (true/false)
        prevText: "Previous",           //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
        nextText: "Next",               //String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item

        // Secondary Navigation
        keyboard: true,                 //Boolean: Allow slider navigating via keyboard left/right keys
        multipleKeyboard: false,        //{NEW} Boolean: Allow keyboard navigation to affect multiple sliders. Default behavior cuts out keyboard navigation with more than one slider present.
        mousewheel: false,              //{UPDATED} Boolean: Requires jquery.mousewheel.js (https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) - Allows slider navigating via mousewheel
        pausePlay: false,               //Boolean: Create pause/play dynamic element
        pauseText: 'Pause',             //String: Set the text for the "pause" pausePlay item
        playText: 'Play',               //String: Set the text for the "play" pausePlay item

        // Special properties
        controlsContainer: "",          //{UPDATED} Selector: USE CLASS SELECTOR. Declare which container the navigation elements should be appended too. Default container is the FlexSlider element. Example use would be ".flexslider-container". Property is ignored if given element is not found.
        manualControls: "",             //Selector: Declare custom control navigation. Examples would be ".flex-control-nav li" or "#tabs-nav li img", etc. The number of elements in your controlNav should match the number of slides/tabs.
        sync: "",                       //{NEW} Selector: Mirror the actions performed on this slider with another slider. Use with care.
        asNavFor: "",                   //{NEW} Selector: Internal property exposed for turning the slider into a thumbnail navigation for another slider

        // Carousel Options
        itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
        itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
        minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
        maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
        move: 0,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.

        // Callback API
        start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
        before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
        after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
        end: function(){},              //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
        added: function(){},            //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is added
        removed: function(){}           //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is removed
    });
}
```

Comment: If you check the console you probably see an error initializing flexslider because it doesnt exist yet. i.e the Html code hasnt loaded in yet.  Retry those events that didnt work, but this time add a timeout function that then runs (setup_flexslider()). Hopefully if you get the timing right the slider should load in a bit faster faster. -- https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/ -- you can try preloading the 1st image on the slider to speed it up even further -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: There is no error in the console.  The html has loaded. It does have something to with jquery mobile dynamic pages though.  I am experimenting with slick.js and getting the same time of problem.  I found found people complaining about similar issues.  It seems to have something to do with not knowing what the 'width' is on hidden elements.  I'm trying to figure out a fix now.  Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: You may not see an error if ($('.flexslider')) is on page 1 and 2. Try ($('.flexslidera')) and ($('.flexsliderb')) and  see if you get an error. Can you do demo on JSFiddle

Comment: After spending several days researching this issue it is really not possible because Flexslider can not get the 'width()' of hidden elements.  All of the carousel plugins suffer from this.  It's a jquery issue.  I was able to hack and use workarounds to get it to 95% working but I kept running into issue after issue.  I even had to modify flexslider.js.  My code became cumbersome with the hack so I abandoned the idea.  I believe this could be fixed if the flexslider developer coded it as such.  It's beyond my reach to do it myself.